# How to use AWS CLI with Digital Ocean Spaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, digital-ocean, aws-cli

How to use AWS CLI with Digital Ocean Spaces? Is it possible?

I tried to add my key id and secret to `.aws/credentials` but I got:

> An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the ListBuckets
>   operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our
>   record

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order to use the AWS CLI with object storage service that provide an S3-compatible API like DigitalOcean Spaces, you must also configure a custom endpoint.

This can be done on the command line using the `--endpoint` flag:

```
aws s3 ls --endpoint=https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that there's no way currently to have a default endpoint.  You gotta specify it every time.  I usually alias it for convenience:  `alias awsdo='aws --endpoint=https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com'`

Comment: Also, commands like `aws s3 sync` do _not_ work with spaces endpoints, so the working alternative is using rclone.

Comment: @Niloct's comment may have been true at the time of posting, but it is no longer true as I am able to use `aws s3 sync` with spaces endpoints.

Comment: @OnelHarrison thanks for your update. Anyway rclone has a very nice feature that only copies files changed in last n minutes without traversing the spaces file structure, and that is REALLY fast. I'm using it with success.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to set the flag in each command, you can simply:

**Set the `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL_S3` environment variable as `https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`.**

Then you can run the commands without the `--endpoint` flag, e.g. `aws s3 ls`.